# Zend db - UPDATE does not work

Tags: php, zend-db

I'm using Zend db to update a record in a MySQL table.  I have a SELECT that gets a uuid; and then the following to update the same record:

```
$data = array(
    'fieldname' => 'foobar',
);

$where = array();
$where["uuid = ?"] = $uuid;

$db->update('customers', $data, $where);
```

Unfortunately the record does not update, and I don't get an error message.  The uuid is correct.

Comment: The MySQL user has permission to update tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was missing the execute.  I ended up doing something like this:

```
$update = $db->update('customers');
$update->where(['uuid' => $uuid]);
$update->set(['fieldname' => 'foobar']);

$statement = $db->prepareStatementForSqlObject($update);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

This worked fine.